# i-check checkbox in fooTable Header <th> not working

Tags: footable, icheck

In [FooTable 3.1.4](https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable) I want to use a pretified [i-Check checkbox](http://icheck.fronteed.com/) for a checkAll functionality in the Header of the table.

This is the HTML without i-Check:

```
<th data-type="html" data-sortable="false"
    data-filterable="false" style="display: table-cell;"
    class="footable-last-visible">Choose
    <input name="check_all" class="all" type="checkbox">
</th>
```

When we run this script **without** i-Checks it runs fine. However - applying i-Checks makes the prettified checkbox unclickable - We are unable to check / uncheck.

This is the HTML with i-Check applied:

```
<th class="footable-last-visible" data-type="html" data-sortable="false" 
    data-filterable="false" style="display: table-cell;">Kies
    <div class="icheckbox_square-green" style="position: relative;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="check_all" class="all" 
        style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
          <ins style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"
               class="iCheck-helper">
         </ins>
   </div>
</th>
```

So it seems FooTable does not accept the i-Checks modified HTML in the head of the table. I did find a (closed) Github Issue post addressing the problem :

> "the issue was that the sorting component worked off of a click on the
>   entire TH element and had a call to e.preventDefault() in the handler.
>   This was basically killing the default click behavior of elements
>   placed within the header element. I've since removed this limitation
>   and it will be released in the next version shortly."

But this post does not clarify as of which version of FooTable this problem is solved.

Or did I make a mistake in the code ..... So - any input much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your script must be:

```
//first
$('.table').footable();

//after
$('#checkall').on('ifChecked ifUnchecked',function(evant){
      if(evant.type == 'ifChecked')
        $('.check').iCheck('check');
      else
        $('.check').iCheck('uncheck');
    });
```